# CouchDB View : Add document as a new field to a document

Tags: couchdb

Let's suppose I have these two documents :

```
{
 "type": "ip",
 "_id": "321",
 "key1": "10",
 "key2": "20",
 "ip_config": { 
       "ip": "127.0.0.1",
       "connexion": "WIFI" 
 }
}
```

---

```
{
 "type": "device",
 "_id": "1",
 "key1": "10",
 "key2": "20",
 "device": { 
       "port": "8808",
       "bits": 46 
 }
}
```

I want to generate a view in CouuchDB that gives me the  following output :

```
{

 "key1": "10",
 "key2": "20",
 "ip_config": { 
       "port": "8808",
       "bits": 46 
 },
  "device": { 
       "port": "8808",
       "bits": 46 
 }
}
```

What is the map function that can help me get this output ?

Comment: Duplicates of `_id` don't fly.  Is there supposed to be some relation between the documents that is not being shown? For example something like [3.2.3. Joins With Views](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/joins.html#linked-documents)?

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake when entering the id of the two examples. Each document has its own _id. It's corrected in the post now.

Comment: What exactly defines the unique join? e.g. given docs A and B, A.key1 === B.key1 && A.key2 === B.key2 ?

Comment: Yes. The fields where the join will be applied are key1 and key2. So given the first and second doc I gave in the example, it's doc1.key1== doc2.key1 && doc2.key2 == doc1.key2

Comment: The map function supplies one and only one document so there is no way to merge two documents as presented and since the documents have no referential context the usual "joins with views" strategy won't work here. Denormalizing the data - e.g. have both device and ip_config in a single document - would be ideal.  Otherwise the alternatives require client side processing and simple view(s) based on say type and keys.

Comment: Thank you @RamblinRose . Yes that was the answer all along, Couch cannot perform such join functions. So we ended up with merging the two in one document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@RamblinRose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4964791/ramblinrose) points out, you cannot "join" documents with a view. The only thing you can do is emit the keys that are common between the docs (in this case it looks like `key1` and `key2` identify this relationship).

So if you had a database called `devices` and created a design document called `test` with a view called device-view with a map function:

```
function (doc) {
  emit([doc.key1, doc.key2], null);
}
```

Then you would be able to obtain all the documents related to the combination of key1 and key2 with:

https://host/devices/_design/test/_view/device-view?include_docs=true&key=[%2210%22,%2220%22]

This would give you:

```
{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"1","key":["10","20"],"value":null,"doc":{"_id":"1","_rev":"1-630408a91350426758c0932ea109f4d5","type":"device","key1":"10","key2":"20","device":{"port":"8808","bits":46}}},
{"id":"321","key":["10","20"],"value":null,"doc":{"_id":"321","_rev":"1-09d9a676c37f17c04a2475492995fade","type":"ip","key1":"10","key2":"20","ip_config":{"ip":"127.0.0.1","connexion":"WIFI"}}}
]}
```

This doesn't do the join, so you would have to process them to obtain a single document.